# What are the difference between the Traditional Logic and the Fuzzy Logic

Tags: artificial-intelligence, fuzzy-logic

Please explain the differences about Traditional and Fuzzy Logics(FLS).

It will help understand about those systems to beginners(Like me).

Comment: What do you not understand from the on-line explanations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fuzzy Logic** (FL) is a method of reasoning that resembles human reasoning. The approach of FL imitates the way of decision making in humans that involves all intermediate possibilities between digital values YES and NO.

The conventional logic block that a computer can understand takes precise input and produces a definite output as TRUE or FALSE, which is equivalent to a human’s YES or NO.

**Traditional logic**: a system of formal logic mainly concerned with the syllogistic forms of deduction that is based on Aristotle and includes some of the changes and elaborations made by the Stoics and the Scholastics: Aristotelian logic — compare immediate inference, opposition, subject-predicate, syllogism, symbolic logic

FOR MORE INFO ABOUT THE FUZZY lOGIC SEE THIS :

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/artificial_intelligence/artificial_intelligence_fuzzy_logic_systems.htm

I hope that I could help you to understand the difference.